# How to modify select2 serach box text on keyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to change the text of select2 search box on keyup event.

Suppose whenever we will write a Bangla digit it will automatically convert into an English digit

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
    <label for="">Select Number</label>
    <select name="number" id="number" class="form-control select">
        <option value="1"  selected  disabled>Select Number</option>
        <option value="2" >123654</option>
        <option value="3" >654564</option>
        <option value="4" >879871</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <span id="error_name" class="has-error"></span>
</div>
```

```js
$(".select").select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert in event this:

```
$('#mySelect2').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: its not working